# How to share DB link with another schema?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have access to two schema. Only one of them has previleges to create a DB link. I want the other schema also to use this DB link. Also I do not have intentions of creating a public DB link. Is this possible in Oracle SQL?

Comment: From the schema where you do not have privilege to create DB link, you could do to access any object as `schema.objectname@dblinkname` Is that you are looking for?

Comment: @Polppan: consider, 2 schemas `user1` and `user2` in dev database. From `user1` I am creating a db link to prod database named `new_link`. I need this `new_link` to be available for `user2` also. From `user2` I should be able to access `schema.objectname@new_link`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  A database link is either public or private.  If it is private, you cannot grant another schema access to the database link.

It is likely, however, that you can solve whatever business problem you have without needing to grant `user2` access to the database link owned by `user1`. Commonly, for example, you would create a view in the `user1` schema that queries a table over the database link and then grant `user2` access to that view.